# viewcontroller navigation pattern from fullscreen controller to tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

Hello everybody and thank you in advance for your help!
I'm going to develop my first iPad (not universal) application and i've some doubt about how to realize the ViewController Pattern.
The first `ViewController` (`rootViewController`, right?) will be a `fullscreen` view for login.
After authentication, the second `viewcontroller` will be a `UITabbarController`.
Do you have any suggestion to realize that pattern? Do I have to replace `rootViewController` after login?

Answer (score 0):

your root view controller will be UINavigationController.
The login screen will be the root view for navigation controller.
You need not change the root view controller. you will stack them over in navigation controller.

Comment: If i use a navigation controller as rootview, i think i have to push tabcontroller after login, right? In this way i get back button, and this is not what i would realize ..

Comment: after successful login you will push a new view and that view will have a tab bar.

Comment: @user1969306 See try to understand this First there is a window and nav controller is root view. Then login controller. then after login you push a new view which has tabbar.

Comment: Ok .. but when i push the new view with tabbar, navigation stack present me the back button. I'd like the tabcontroller would be like a rootcontroller, not as a child of logincontroller ..

Comment: @djfabrix Then go the other way around 
root view controller = login first
afterlogin rootViewController = newView with tab
This new view will also have navigation control ie; different navigation control for different tab.
if log out button is pressed then root view controller = loginViewController

Comment: Ok! This is perfect for me! Thank you very much!